# NSURLSession cannot set cookies when url contains port number

Tags: ios7

I have an ios backend running on a port other than standard port 80. I create the NSURLRequest with specific port：

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.com:81/user/authen"]];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:nil];
[task resume];

NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSLog(@"[COOKIESTORAGE]: %@", cookieStorage);
```

After authentication, backend set some cookies:

```
Set-Cookie: UID=12; expires=Sat, 18-Jan-2014 09:09:09 GMT; domain=test.com:81
```

However, the app's cookie storage wasn't set. Even if I changed the port to 80, it also didn't work.

I found it works only when I removed the port number.